# How to get values from SQLite database fro 2 entries and if they are correct then instert time/date they were entered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I've been learning Tkinter where I have two entries **entry_in** and **entry_out**, and I also have a button **ENTER**, what I did is to define a function for my button **def enter():** and then use SQLite to connect with my button and entries, inmy database I have a table called **superuser** and a column **idcard**:

```py
def enter():

   conn = sqlite3.connect('login_file1.db')
   c = conn.cursor()

   cardin = entry_in.get()
   cardout = entry_out.get()

   c.execute('SELECT * FROM superuser WHERE idcard = ? AND idcard = ?', (cardin, cardout))

   if c.fetchall():
         messagebox.showinfo(title='Ente succsefully')
   else:
         messagebox.showerror(tittle=None)

   c.close()
```

My conditionals only work when both entries are filled, but I want it works only if one of them are entered, I mean if **entry_in** is correct then show 'entered sucssefully' and **INSERT** the actual **date/time** to my database(I have a date and time columns to store it), same for my **entry_out**

psdt: I'm trying to do is an Attendance System, any advise please let me know.

Comment: Why two `idcard = ?` in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @acw1668 Because my entries should have the same values from idcard column in my database.

Comment: You may use `OR` instead of `AND` because using `AND` the condition will always be FALSE if `cardin != cardout`.

Comment: Where do you want to insert and what do you want to insert.

Comment: @CoolCloud I have a sqlite database and I've created a table , in that table I have some columns, idcard, name,  surname, time in, time out, date.,  etc), what I want to do is to insert the actual time and date everytime the idcard (entry_in or entry_out) number is correct, record it maybe in other table with name surname time in time out and date